# Password Policy - Prohibit Prefedined Passwords

Tags: password

I know there are a lot of questions regarding editing the default password complexity, and they've been really helpful in understanding how passwords are handled by Ubuntu. But I haven't found anything about blocking predefined passwords. Is this possible to do with Ubuntu?

For context, we have a number of old passwords that have been in use for 10+ years and we know that they've been compromised. However, folks will still use them because they're easy to remember. I'm looking for a way to block those passwords specifically. They meet complexity requirements, and raising the requirements to deter one or two passwords would be a bit overkill.

TIA for any advice!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189746/how-to-blacklist-common-passwords-on-unix-systems

Comment: @user68186 Oops, sort of a big detail to omit. Currently using 18.04

Comment: If you are able to do it following the link by @xenoid don't forget to write your own answer and provide all the details (not just a link) so that it can help others.